# CXF log File issue in Jboss6

Tags: jboss, redhat, jboss-eap-6

cxf log is not getting populated in the applications when trying to migrate my application to Jboss6 from Jboss5.Issue is resolved by adding a file named org.apache.cxf.Logger in /META-INF/cxf folder structure.is this is the only solution ? and I want to know that what is forcing  us to add this file in META-INF